# Create custom action in Yii2 Rest API

Tags: api, rest, yii2

I am working with yii2 , and I want to create rest api. I read yii2 rest api quick start documentation, but in there you can use only default actions(index/view/create/delete/list...). It is working fine

But I want to create another action for example

```
public function actionPurchasedcard(){
     //some code
}
```

But I couldn't it. Help me please, how to create custome action in yii2 Rest api.

config.php

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'enableStrictParsing' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        [
            'class'=>'yii\rest\UrlRule',
            'controller'=>[
                'v1/resource',
            ]
        ],
    ]
]
```

document root:

```
htdocs/myapi/api/web/
```

I am calling like this :
http://myapi/v1/resource/purchasedcard

Thanks.(sorry my english not good)

Comment: This is the way but what happen?. "I couldn't" not help.. show your rest url and  your controller

Comment: What URL do you use to call the action? Perhaps you should post your controller code here as well

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You may set the `extraPatterns` key in a rule to add a new actions, like so:

```
'rules' => [
    [
        'class'=>'yii\rest\UrlRule',
        'controller'=>[
            'v1/resource',
        ],
        'extraPatterns' => [
            'GET purchasedcard' => 'purchasedcard',
        ]
    ],
]
```

You may want to add other properties to the rule such as `prefix` or `only` depending on what you want to achieve. Look at the [full documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rest-urlrule.html#properties) to know more. Look at [guide examples](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-routing.html) too: there is an example of an `extraPattern` with the `search` action near the end of this guide.

Comment: Also to pass params you can do the following: 'GET purchasedcard/<some_id>' => 'purchasedcard',